# Redux not running on page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently working on a react app with redux. When I attempt to navigate to the ticket page, nothing will load and I get a 'Cannot read properties of null'error [Console error I receive when coming from a different page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQJWl.png) because redux will not run and the page is dependent on redux running so I can get the state of the ticket. However, when I click the reload button in the browser, redux will then run and everything works like it should. [Redux state after refreshing the page in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oksUO.png)

```
function Ticket() {
  const { ticket } = useSelector((state) => state.tickets);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { ticketId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTicket(ticketId)).unwrap().catch(toast.error);
  }, [dispatch, ticketId]);

  return (
    <>
      <BackButton />
      <div className='container flex '>
        <h1>{ticket.subject}</h1>
        <h1 className='capitalize'>Ticket Status: {ticket.status}</h1>
      </div>
```

```
// Get user ticket
export const getTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  'tickets/getSingleTicket',
  async (ticketId, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketService.getTicket(ticketId, token);
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(extractErrorMessage(error));
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I believe it is working but ticket is being set to to null initially. You could add a null check in your render statement to check if ticket then print your current code. Else show a loading message until state can update.